# How do I access ipa files from an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to inspect one of the applications that I have downloaded from the iPad app store on my iPad 15.

I assume that it comes with an ipa file.

To locate the app folder or any ipa file, I open the "Files" app and enter "ipa".

Nothing is found.

Are these files hidden from the user?
How do I access / find them?

Thank you!

ps: The app is only available on the iPad app store, not for Mac.

ps2: I know that this board does not fit 100%.
However, I don't see which other board might fit.

ps3:
When I search for "How do I access files on an iPad", I find hundreds of entries explaining how to find documents that the user has created on an iPad, but not where the apps themselves are stored.

Comment: When I used iOS, Apple hid basically everything from the user. The files app was only useful to find things downloaded from websites, not files downloaded by apps, nor the app store.

Answer (score 0):

AppStore hides this information due to security reasons, so you would not be able to access or locate the ipa file so one would be prevented performing reverse engineering or any other ways to violate the security and data that app provides.

Comment: I don't think I realized that this was due to security reasons, more so just proprietary Apple things, but it begs the question: Isn't Security via Obscurity generally seen as insufficient for the real-world? I'm sure there are workarounds to find the file anyway.